# Dropbox SDK Catch-22: How to get Dropbox SDK and Sync SDK to coexist?

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm successfully using the DropBox SDK (i.e., my APP_KEY and APP_SECRET are functioning properly). But now I'm stuck trying to add the Sync SDK into the app.  BTW, the only reason I am trying to add in the Sync SDK is to get shortened URLs. So if there's a better/simpler solution I'm all ears.

My current problem is if I try to include **both** Sync and Dropbox SDKs in the build path I get a build error:

> Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/dropbox/client2/android/AuthActivity$1;

If I remove the DropBox SDK from the build path the app will build but then crashes with a

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.dropbox.client2.session.Session$AccessType

error when it executes this line:
`final static private AccessType ACCESS_TYPE = AccessType.APP_FOLDER;`

I've already included both the "com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity" and "com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAuthActivity" activities in the Manifest.

How can I resolve this Catch-22?

Related to this question I'm also wondering:

1. Is there a way to get standard http:// URL's instead of https:// URLs using only the Dropbox SDK?
2. Even after I get the Sync SDK working will I even be able to get shortened URLs for files in my app's folder (i.e., they're not in a public folder)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to share a file and get a short link for it, take a look at the `short_url` parameter of `/shares`: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#shares.

If that's not what you're trying to do, can you please explain? You mention URLs a few times, but it's not clear to me what URLs you're talking about.

As to including both the Core API and Sync API in the same project, I believe it's possible but will require renaming some classes. (At least that's been my experience in iOS, not sure about Android.)

Comment: To be clearer, as you suspected, I'm referring tothe URLs needed to provide to others to enable them to view the files in my app's Dropbox account.
I will look into your shares suggestion.  I've not used that API before.  
Regarding using the core and Sync APIs together, do you have any guidance on which classes must be renamed?  Thanks!

Comment: I've looked at the shares documentation but don't understand how to implement it.  I know you mentioned iOS, but I'm wondering if you have any code examples for Android.  I looked on SO but came up empty.

Comment: At first glance, it looks to me like the Android SDK doesn't support passing the `short_url` parameter to `/shares`. Updating my answer to include some code...

Comment: Oh, actually it looks like, per the documentation, `short_url` defaults to `true`, so there should be no need to set it. But you're not getting back a short URL?

Comment: Just use `client.share(path)` to call the `share` method.

Comment: I get the path by using `dropBoxFilePath = _dropBoxAPI.share(dropBoxItem.path);` (where _dropBoxAPI equates to 'client').  Then I get the URL with `fileURLString = getShareURL(dropBoxFilePath.url);` Unfortunately that returns the full https:// style URL (e.g., https colon //www dot dropbox dot com/s/....... ).  Bottom line, I still do not see an option to get the short URL.

Comment: According to the documentation, the object you get from `.share` should have a `url` field with the short URL: https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.4-docs/index.html. Are we both looking at the same library?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33675/discussion-between-peteh-and-smarx)

Comment: Pls could you point me to the specific class or method you are referring to in the docs.  I'd be happy to take it from there. thanks!

Comment: Oh, sorry for the bad link. Here's the `share` method: https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.4-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#share(java.lang.String)